# Display random number on Bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5, popover

I have a bootstrap popover on a button that I would like to display a random number every time its clicked. However my current implementation only displays the first number generated and is not updated on subsequent clicks.

Here's my code.

```html
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded" data-bs-toggle="popover" id="d100">
    Popover Button
  </button>  

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#d100').click(function() {
    var popoverContent = generalDice(1,100,0);

    // Show the popover
    $(this).popover({
      content: popoverContent,
      placement: 'top',
      trigger: 'manual'
    }).popover('show');


    // Remove the popover when clicking outside
    $(document).on('click', function(event) {
      if (!$(event.target).closest('#d100').length) {
        $('#d100').popover('hide').popover('destroy');
      }
    });

    // Prevent click event propagation to avoid immediate removal
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most Bootstrap components have [events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/popovers/#events) to leverage instead of writing all your own. (The click handlers already exist.) You could call your update function on the `show` event instead, and use the [`setContent` method](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/popovers/#methods) to update the value.

I haven't used jQuery with Bootstrap since v5 was released, so you'll have to do some translation if you prefer that. See [youmightnotneedjquery.com](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com) for help transitioning away from that increasingly unnecessary dependency.

```js
const popoverTriggerEl = document.querySelector('#d100');
let popoverVal = 0;

popover = new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl, {
  content: popoverVal,
  placement: 'right'
});

popoverTriggerEl.addEventListener('show.bs.popover', () => {
  popoverVal = Math.random(); // replace with a call to your function

  popover.setContent({
    '.popover-body': popoverVal.toString()
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded m-5" data-bs-toggle="popover" id="d100">
  Popover Button
</button>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason this does not work with bootstrap 5.1, which is what I was using. As soon as I loaded the 5.2 cdn, everything works as expected.

Comment: It seems that `setContent()` was added after 5.1. You can convert to [older methods](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/popovers/#methods) or update your library. Chances are 5.2 will work without issue.

Comment: It seems loading the 5.2 for one page works fine. I'm not building the page from scratch, I'm using [Quarto](https://quarto.org/), which loads 5.1 by default, so I was worried adding 5.2 on top of that would be an issue.

Comment: You should not load two versions of a library. That's a problem for several reasons. It looks like Quarto allows you to modify the default theme configuration to eliminate that.